# Created android module, trying to reference a layout but can't

Tags: android, android-layout, android-module

I have created an android module and inside a Fragment defined in the module I am trying to inflate a `R.layout.my_module_fragment`:

Unfortunately it's not working:

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_module_fragment, container)
```

It throws `Unresolved reference: my_module_fragment`

build.gradle:

```
android {
    resourcePrefix 'mymodule'

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }

    dataBinding.enabled = true

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}
```

I have created the layout under:

```
/Main_Project/MY_MODULE/main/res/layout
```

Comment: module has own resources, you should create new layouts in module. You can't use 'app' module resources in library-modules, It will make circular dependencies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R import was linked to another R.

Answer (score 0):

As i am not able to comment so i post it there
Have you added your module in app level build.gradle dependencies?

```
api project(path: ': your_module')
```